# Cannot run a car locally on Code Rally beta (1.5?)

Tags: code-rally

I installed the latest beta version of Code Rally, following the [instructions on IBM developers site](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/manually_installing_code_rally?lang=en). I believe this is a beta of version 1.5, but there is no indication on the page and downloads of previous stable versions are not available either. I installed Code Rally on

- Linux - Fedora 25  (also in Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 7 ultimate)
- Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

I managed to create an intermediate and run it on a remote server. But I didn't succeed in running it on the Liberty server installed locally. I installed the Liberty server from the **Servers** tab on the lower left region of the Code Rally perspective. It is listening to port 9080 (default).

Then, I used the **Server** tab of the upper left to create a new server with `Host: localhost` and `Port: 9080`.  When I **Save** this configuration the dialog box header says the **Status: Online** and **Version: <1.3.1.2**. If I press **Login** and enter an id I receive a message successful login message.

[image]

Nevertheless, if I press **View leaderboard** then Eclipse opens a web browser tab with a WebSphere error message saying that context root was not found, as can be seen in the following image.

[image]

If I press **Enter spectator mode** I also get an error message. It seems that the Code Rally server webapp was not loaded to Liberty but, unlike in previous Code Rally versions (at least according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erxAWAZLvDI)).

If I try to run the car, using the **Enter race on...** command on the context menu of my car I get a message saying the server cannot be connected, as seen in the following screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone point me to what am I doing wrong? Do I need to install a Code Rally webapp in Liberty? Where do I get it?

This is a beta version but I would in fact prefer a stable version. Are the previous stable versions still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm part of the Code Rally team at IBM.

To run on a local server you will need a 1.5 release of the Code Rally race simulation server - that has not been released yet as there were still a few outstanding bugs. To run a race where the AI and the race simulation are both on the same machine you need to run that webapp on the Liberty server once it is available (which should be soon).

The current beta is labelled as such as there's not a local race server download for this version - the code rally betas are stable on the client side before release, so the only beta part is the race simulation server. There were quite a few issues with the 1.4 release which have been fixed in 1.5 - unfortunately the move to 1.5 brought some breaking changes to the API where we can't have a mix of 1.4 and 1.5 servers/clients. As we ran an online contest racing on our cloud servers through December we had to update all the cloud servers to v1.5 so people could enter the contest with the new client.

For now I'd suggest running a race on one of the cloud servers - your vehicle code will run locally if you build an "agent" AI for seeing what is happening in your code.

edit

The 1.5 race simulation server is now available for download - the download link and install instructions are here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/beta_installer

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Do you have any idea when the 1.5 server will be available? I will be teaching a software architecture course next semester, starting February, and I would like to give a warm-up assignment based on Code Rally. I did it before but using an old version that didn't require an application server, but it doesn't work in recent version of Java  and Eclipse.

Comment: I can't give you an exact date - the previous version (1.4) of Code Rally did require an application server as well for running the AI code. The server side was always either use the cloud servers we run or spin up a local version. I'll add a new comment here when the 1.5 server is uploaded.

Comment: I was referring to a much older version of IBM games, including not only Code Rally but also Code Ruler and Code Invaders. I think it was originally written by Tim de Boers.

Comment: Understood - this is based on the original version from Tim, but it has been taken through significant re-writes to make it an online multiplayer game. The 1.5 server is now available for download, with the instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/beta_installer

Comment: Thanks. I managed to install it and run the within Eclipse (Linux) but I had to add ALLOW_LINUX_DERBY=true to server.env

Eclipse crashed the first time I tried to view the race but now seems to be working .